# incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int even there're no strings

Tags: java, string, int

I am trying to learn Java programming but when i tried to make a simple BMI calculator i get this error, The error is generated on line 7, There are no "Stings" to convert it to int actually all are "int" here! Please help!

```
package com.sparkedleads.bminew;

public class MyBmiNew {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int myBmi = myBmiCal("20", "10");
        System.out.println("Your BMI is " + myBmi);

    }

    public static int myBmiCal(int massOfPerson, int heightOfPerson){

        int bmiScore = massOfPerson/heightOfPerson;

        return bmiScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: `myBmiCal(20, 10)`

Comment: "_There are no "Strings"_" `"20"` and `"10"` are Strings, not ints.

Comment: The compiler's exactly correct - those *are* strings. I'm not sure why you think they're `int`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing two arguments as String type, "20", "10":

```
int myBmi = myBmiCal("20", "10");
```

But it should be int type:

```
int myBmi = myBmiCal(20, 10);
```

"" - it means just empty String in Java. "20" - it means String with value 20. "20" and 20 are different types in Java. Here is [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) to learn more about it.

Comment: omg i am so dumb :( thank you sir for helping a noob like me!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

your error is `int myBmi = myBmiCal("20", "10");`

putting a number in quotes makes it a string so it should be: `int myBmi = myBmiCal(20, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `"` from your parameter because function need `int` param and you sent `String` params

`int myBmi = myBmiCal(20, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem with your code is that you have passed the arguments to

```
myBmiCal("20","10");
```

This makes the compiler think that 20 and 10 are actually String arguments instead of taking them as integer type.
make it to `myBmiCal(20,10);`

Let us also remember that our computers running java are nothing but dumb machines which only follow our instructions.